# C Parsing /proc/stat to calculate current CPU usage for each core

Tags: c, ubuntu, cpu-usage

**I apologize for my incompetence in advance. I need this for a class I'm taking, but everything in C went right over my head, and have been struggling to hold on.**

I'm trying to parse information from /proc/stat so I can calculate the "current" CPU usage for each core and print it out. I'm going to calculate the "current" usage by subtracting an older version's numbers from a newer version of /proc/stat and adding the resulting numbers to the most recent set (at least i think so, I'll cross that bridge when I get there). Regardless, I'm kind of confused as to how to parse the information. I know that the results look like this:

```
cpu  1135030 3367 440838 5175504 85602 0 78716 0 0 0
cpu0 284682 935 110466 3027379 55475 0 27688 0 0 0
cpu1 282910 969 109421 719958 8029 0 22700 0 0 0
cpu2 284182 648 110727 715945 9275 0 16262 0 0 0
cpu3 283256 814 110223 712220 12822 0 12065 0 0 0
```

and I know that the top row is aggregate of all the cores, with rows representing user, nice, system, idle, iowait, irq, softirq, steal, guest, and guest_nice respectively.

My original code is :

```
int main() {
    FILE *state1;
    FILE *state2;
    int oldNumbers[7];
    int newNumbers[7];

    state1 = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    sleep(1);
    state2 = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");

    fscanf(state1, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", oldNumbers[0], oldNumbers[1], oldNumbers[2], oldNumbers[3], oldNumbers[4], oldNumbers[5], oldNumbers[6]);
    fscanf(state2, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", newNumbers[0], newNumbers[1], newNumbers[2], newNumbers[3], newNumbers[4], newNumbers[5], newNumbers[6]);

    fclose(state1);
    fclose(state2);

    return 0;
}
```

I see why it doesn't work, since my oldNumbers[] and newNumbers[] aren't pointers, but when i make them pointers, they don't work either. That said, I have absolutely no idea how to move on from here, and any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- You don't need two pointers to the file, only one, then you can just move back to the beginning of the file for the second read.
- As already mentioned, you need to use pointers in `fscanf()`

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *statFP;
    int oldNumbers[7];
    int newNumbers[7];
    int diffNumbers[7];
    char cpu[10];  // Not used

    statFP = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");

    fscanf(statFP,
            "%s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
            cpu,
            &oldNumbers[0], 
            &oldNumbers[1],
            &oldNumbers[2],
            &oldNumbers[3],
            &oldNumbers[4],
            &oldNumbers[5],
            &oldNumbers[6]);

    sleep(1);
    rewind(statFP);

    fscanf(statFP,
            "%s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
            cpu,
            &newNumbers[0],
            &newNumbers[1],
            &newNumbers[2],
            &newNumbers[3],
            &newNumbers[4],
            &newNumbers[5],
            &newNumbers[6]);

    fclose(statFP);

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 7; ii++) {
        diffNumbers[ii] = newNumbers[ii] - oldNumbers[ii];
        printf("%d: %d\n", ii, diffNumbers[ii]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As another note, there is a Linux package called `sysstat` (https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat) which contains all kinds of code for parsing the information in /proc. It is worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Minimally, you need to scan past the initial string before you can scan the numbers. Of course, `fscanf` takes pointers.

```
    fscanf(state1, "%*s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &oldNumbers[0], &oldNumbers[1], &oldNumbers[2], &oldNumbers[3], &oldNumbers[4], &oldNumbers[5], &oldNumbers[6]);
    fscanf(state2, "%*s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &newNumbers[0], &newNumbers[1], &newNumbers[2], &newNumbers[3], &newNumbers[4], &newNumbers[5], &newNumbers[6]);
```

After that, you would need to scan past the 3 remaining numbers before you can scan the input on the next line (if that is what you intend to do).

And, `/proc` largely works by providing the current information as you are reading the file, not populating something at the time you open it. So, you will need to read the first file, then wait one second, then read the second file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This has made this seem so much easier. You're a lifesaver, friend